# Slipstream multiple .msp patches in an administrative install point and verify it

Tags: windows-installer, patch, administration, msp

I would like to install several .msp patches in an administrative install point of a MSI setup. I did it for 1 msp file with the command "msiexec /p patch.msp" but I would like to know if  is possible and SAFE to apply several patches to the administrative install point e.g "msiexec /p patch1.msp patch2.msp patch3.msp" or even do the administrative installation and patch installation simultaneously e.g "msiexec /a setup.msi  /p patch1.msp patch2.msp patch3.msp"

Also, is there any way to verify that the patch applied successfully? You think that just the exit code of the installation process is enough?

Thank you,

J.

Answer (score 1):

First, run

- msiexec /a setup.msi
- select a path

Then apply the patches:

- msiexec /a [path from step one]setup.msi /p patch1.msp
- msiexec /a [path from step one]setup.msi /p patch2.msp
- msiexec /a [path from step one]setup.msi /p patch3.msp